# Problem with LAN cable connection

Tags: drivers, ethernet, realtek

I have dual booted my PC ( which has windows installed) with Ubuntu. My LAN cable works well on windows but it;s not working with Ubuntu, it's just showing up Ethernet connection. Do I have to change some settings or I have to reboot my PC again with Ubuntu? Thanks in advance.

I am in college and I need to login for Internet connection the page isn't showing up in browser on LAN while on working over Wifi it's working.

output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA3 'Eth|Net'`:

```
tarptaeya@TARPTAEYA:~$ lspci -knn | grep -EA3 'Eth|Net'
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:820c]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 81)
    DeviceName: Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 3165 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.0 Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165 [8086:4010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: The question is unclear. You need to add details. How do you use your Ethernet cable? Where is it connected? What is the problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA3 'Eth|Net'` terminal command.

Comment: I have updated my question with output for `lspci -knn | grep -EA3 'Eth|Net'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the internet by Wi-Fi and run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install r8168-dkms
```

then reboot.

This will install the Realtek driver for this new revision `0a`